# KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ ...] are in the [index]" while plotting a pandapower network

Tags: plot, pandapower

I am new in pandapower. I wanna plot an IEEE 33 bus network, but i got the following error:
my code:

plot.fuse_geodata(net)
bc = plot.create_bus_collection(net, net.bus.index, size=.2, color=colors[0], zorder=10)
#bc = plot.create_bus_collection(net, nbi, size=.2, color=colors[0], zorder=10)
tlc, tpc = plot.create_trafo_collection(net, net.trafo.index, color="g")
lcd = plot.create_line_collection(net, net.line.index, color="grey", linewidths=0.5, use_bus_geodata=True)
sc = plot.create_bus_collection(net, net.ext_grid.bus.values, patch_type="rect", size=.5, color="y", zorder=11)
plot.draw_collections([lcd, bc, tlc, tpc, sc], figsize=(8,6))

the error:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 plot.fuse_geodata(net)
----> 2 bc = plot.create_bus_collection(net, net.bus.index, size=.2, color=colors[0], zorder=10)
3 #bc = plot.create_bus_collection(net, nbi, size=.2, color=colors[0], zorder=10)
4 tlc, tpc = plot.create_trafo_collection(net, net.trafo.index, color="g")
5 lcd = plot.create_line_collection(net, net.line.index, color="grey", linewidths=0.5, use_bus_geodata=True)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
6128         if not self._should_compare(target) and not self._should_partial_index(target):
6129             # _should_partial_index e.g. IntervalIndex with numeric scalars
-> 6130             #  that can be matched to Interval scalars.
6131             return self._get_indexer_non_comparable(target, method=None, unique=False)
6132

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,\n            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,\n            33],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"

I wanna see the plot

plotting a pandapower network